# MS Azure web service - issues sending predictive data to Power Bi

Tags: azure, powerbi

I have set up an IoT and ASA that uses data from my Rpi3 and weather station to stream data to Power Bi. This all works fine. I then attempted to use machine learning to predict a rain shower using the following tutorial from MS :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-weather-forecast-machine-learning

This again all works fine when testing in the ML studio test functionality. But when I try and send this data to Power Bi I get a fixed probability of rain that is stuck on 48.99%.

There has been another user that raised an issue with the same problem on the comments section on the above website, he then claims to have fixed the issue by removing all the non-numerical data. I tried the same fix but it came out with a probability range from 7% - 9% - at least it wasn't fixed right!

Has anyone else encountered the same problem with Azure ML web services and streaming analytics to Power Bi.

My query for the ASA is a s follows:

WITH machinelearning AS (
   SELECT EventEnqueuedUtcTime, Temperature, Humidity, machinelearning(Temperature, Humidity) as result from [CwrtCelynWeather]
)
Select System.Timestamp time, CAST (result.[temperature] AS FLOAT) AS temperature, CAST (result.[humidity] AS FLOAT) AS humidity, CAST (result.[Scored Probabilities] AS FLOAT ) AS 'probabalities of rain'
Into [weatherPBi2]
From machinelearning

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been resolved, i ended up rewriting the R script in Azure machine learning studio.